# Font type/name of command is needed

Tags: fonts, pdftex

How do I type in LaTeX the 3 letters reading $ACA_0$ from the excerpt below?
I believe that this is called bezpatkove pismo in the Czech language.

[image]

Comment: `\textsf{ACA}$_0$` or `$\textsf{ACA}_0$`, the `sf` referring to the "sans serif" font family.  Other font families include roman (`\textrm`) and typewriter (`\texttt`).

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I think it should be `$\mathsf{ACA}_0$`.

Comment: @JouleV If the math and text sf-fonts are the same, and if one is not in a script style, then it makes no never mind, best I can tell.  Based on the context of the OP's use case, I still lean to `\textsf`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes it will make a difference `\textsf` would be bold if the outer text is bold also it doesn't get smaller in subscripts by default (it does with amsmath but less efficiently setting everything 4 times in a \mathchoice)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I understand all those distinctions.  My point was that even though it is presented with a subscript 0, it is not obvious to me that the OP wants to treat "ACA" as math item, in preference to a text item. He may prefer it become bolded when presented in a bold caption, for example.

Comment: I think using \mathfoo unless there is overwhelming evidence that \textfoo is better in the context is a good rule to have:-)